# Data transfer and decoding in Odoo

Tags: odoo-8, openerp-8

I want transfer and decode binary data (base64) from a postgresql database through network.

I have tried through Web services for retrieving some data which is working but I want get attachment from `'ir_attachement'` table through the Web services.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Have u tried any things from your side then just add it in your question so that it better to understand the some for easily understand

Comment: from my side i can decode binary data (locally)